# Is it possible to use checkbox change with the combination of class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

This is my code with checkboxes with **one** and **two** classes as shown below

```
<input type="checkbox" class="one" value="1">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="two" value="2">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="one" value="3">
<br/>
```

If the checkbox is checked or unchecked , i have the below code which gets called

```
$(document).on('change', '.[type="checkbox"]', function(event, data){
    alert('checked ');
});
```

My question is , how can i use class also in the event handler ??

I have tried this way

```
$(document).on('change', '.one .[type="checkbox"]', function(event, data){
    alert('checked ');
});
$(document).on('change', '.two .[type="checkbox"]', function(event, data){ 
    alert('checked ');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FdEhf/32/

Answer (score 3):

This is a wrong selector:

```
 '.[type="checkbox"]'
```

You can't have a dot `.` before attribute selectors.

---

Now to answer your question you can use this way:

```
 '.one[type="checkbox"]'
 // make sure you don't have any space in between.
```

---

Well you can have a common class name to each checkbox and you can bind a change event on that class:

```js
$('.commonClass[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(event, data) {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log(this.classList[1]+' checked ');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="commonClass one" value="1">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="commonClass two" value="2">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="commonClass three" value="3">
<br/>
```

You don't need to have a ***event delegation*** way to bind any event unless you  have dynamically generated `:checkbox` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

You can use this selector:

```
.one[type="checkbox"]
```

To break it down, this selector will match any element with the `.one` class that as a type attribute equal to `checkbox`.

You could also just have `[type="checkbox"]` as the selector and then inside the change handler inspect the elements class. This would be useful if you wanted to have slightly different functionality between different checkboxes -

```
$(document).on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', function(event, data){
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' '); // may be multiple classes - split them into an array
    if ( $.inArray( 'one', classes ) ){
      alert('.one was changed!');
    } else {
      alert('some other checkbox was changed!');
    }
});
```

For this simple example it might be overkill but it would allow you to further customise different checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove one extra "." before that `[type="checkbox"]` and second use  only classes like `.one .two` as event listeners and you'll get the result as per your need.